# Visualforce Add Products page in Lightning is redirecting to a blank page

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience, opportunity-lineitem, salesforce-classic

I'm currently working on a migration to Lightning where we have some Visualforce pages, specially in Opportunity.

We are currently facing an issue when trying to open the standard Add Products or Edit Products page, since this are Visualforce pages we haven't been able to open the Lightning Modal to edit the products as this one.

[image]

That modal is from the standard lightning page, we've tried opening the add products with

```
{!URLFOR($Action.OpportunityLineItem.AddProduct,Opportunity.Id)}

{!URLFOR($Action.OpportunityLineItem.EditAllProduct,Opportunity.Id)}
```

Those two open the classic page to add or edit products

[image]

The issue is when trying to save or cancel it goes to a blank page with this error in the console.

[image]

In the OpportunityLineItem buttons and actions, I saw there is a Standard action called MultiAdd which is the one that opens the lightning modal, but tried this code and doesn't work:

```
{!URLFOR($Action.OpportunityLineItem.MultiAdd,Opportunity.Id)}
```

Anybody has a workaround for this? Is this a bug in the platform or is there a configuration missing or something?

Comment: Did you try using the 3rd argument to the URLFOR ? `[RetURL=URLFOR($Action.Opportunity.View,Opportunity.Id)]` - see [related question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/258360/open-add-product-page-in-lightning) (albeit Apex)

Comment: Tried but didn't work. I ended up using the lightning related lists and use the lightning standard modal instead.